# Moving Balls, instantiationExeption

Tags: java, applet

The following program draws a couple of balls on the screen which are supposed to simple bounce around, with no friction force.
I keep getting an instantiationExeption when running the program, without being able to correct it (I'm still new to java :D).

```
package movement;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ball extends StartingPoint {
 /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

int x;
int y;
int radius;
Color color;
// dy will be the velocity of the ball
double dx,dy = 0;
private static final double dt = .2;
private static final double gravity = 9.81;

 Ball(int x, int y, int radius, Color color){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
}

 public Color getCOLOR(Ball ball){
    return ball.color;
 }

public void move(){


        x = (int) (x + dx);

        // 600 being the window height
        if (y > 600 -radius - 1){
            y = 600 - radius - 1;
            dy *= -1;
        }
        else{

            //physics formula for velocity
            dy += gravity * dt;
            //physics formula for displacement with earth-like gravity
            y += (int) .5 * gravity * dt*dt + dy*dt;}

}

public void paintPLUS(Graphics g, Ball ball){

     g.setColor(getCOLOR(ball));
     g.fillOval(x, y, radius, radius);
}


}
```

---

```
// This program creates nbBalles balls which move down in parallel 

package movement;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


public class StartingPoint extends Applet {

    public int startX,startY,startRADIUS, nbColor, n;
    private static final int nbBalles = 50;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Color[] setCOLOR = {Color.black, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.magenta, Color.white, Color.RED, Color.ORANGE};
    ArrayList<Ball> BallList = new ArrayList<Ball>();


    @Override
    public void init() {

        setSize(800,600);

        for (int i = 0; i<nbBalles; i++){
        Random randX = new Random();
        Random randY = new Random();
        Random randRADIUS = new Random();
        startX = randX.nextInt(2000);
        startY = randY.nextInt(700);
        startRADIUS = randRADIUS.nextInt(50)+10;
         Random random = new Random();
         nbColor = random.nextInt(setCOLOR.length);
        BallList.add(new Ball(startX, startY, startRADIUS, setCOLOR[nbColor]));

        }}



    @Override
    public void start() {

            for(Ball ball :BallList){
            Thread thread = new Thread(new BallMovement(ball));
            thread.start();
            }
        }

    class BallMovement implements Runnable{
        private final Ball ball;
        BallMovement(Ball ball){
            this.ball = ball;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                ball.move();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(8);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                repaint();
                }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 2000, 1000);

        for(Ball ball : BallList)
        {

            ball.paintPLUS(g, ball);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
charger : movement.Ball.class ne peut pas être instancié.java.lang.InstantiationException: movement.Ball
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:342)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:806)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:713)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:369)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: I stand by the advice given in my answer -- that Ball should not extend StartingPoint, but my answer was incorrect in that it was not the source of your error. Please tell us how you're trying to run this program.

Comment: A side question of my own: What purpose is served by the nested for-loop inside of your paint method override?

Comment: ahaha, yeah I'm pretty sure it's a mess (the background is pretty ugly), the program runs with eclipse, the concept is just the make 10 balles appearing randomly and bouncing around with respect to the y-axis only with no friction, I seems easy but still doesn't work that well for a reason

Comment: the for loop in paint override is pretty useless, I just made it to produce an original backround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ball should most definitely **not** extend StartingPoint as this gives you a circular reference issue:

StartingPoint contains a List of Ball objects which extend StartingPoint.

Edit: your exception is coming from your trying to run the Ball class and not the StartingPoint class.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but the error is still there :(

Comment: @SwissPhil02: I'm not getting that exception, but when I run your program, I get a visual mess. How are you trying to run your applet?

Comment: @SwissPhil02: OK, I've solved the exception issue -- again, don't have Ball extend StartingPoint, and most importantly, don't try to **run** the Ball class, but rather the StartingPoint class.